# What's new in Google Guice 3?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Guice 3 is just around the corner, but I cannot find a page telling me what's new in this version. So, what's new in Guice 3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Guice 3.0 wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Guice30) has a whole section entitled "New Features" along with a bit on migration.

I suspect that the feature which is in some ways most welcome while also not providing genuinely new functionality is [JSR 330 integration](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JSR330).

Comment: JSR-330 is really nice, we've used a copy of SVN for this exact purpose for the last 6 months.  An official release is most welcome.

Comment: @Kdeveloper: I don't know, to be honest.